# installing latest NPM version

Tags: npm, installation, upgrade

I have NodeJS v20.2.0 installed on Windows 10. But the NPM is on v7.5.2 and I cannot get it to update to v9.7.2.

I have tried

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

on cmd and Powershell with no luck. I get the following error.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
npm ERR! dest C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm-QXjMEw5N
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm-QXjMEw5N'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm-QXjMEw5N'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.npm-QXjMEw5N'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: It says to try running it again as Administrator. Have you done that?

Comment: I tried this using PowerShell as Administrator